# Will the Newton's method be convergent to the root of the following function: $f(x)=\frac{-x}{x^2-1}$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

Will the Newton's method be convergent to the root of the following function, if the starting point $x_0>1$ will be chosen?

$$
f(x)=\frac{-x}{x^2-1}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Newton's method iteration function is

$$N(x)=x-f(x)/f'(x) = \frac{2 x^3}{x^2+1}.$$

Why don't you plug in $x=2$ and see what comes out?  You could then plug that result back in and try a few more iterates to see what's going on.  If you understand the [follow the slope description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#mediaviewer/File:NewtonIteration_Ani.gif) of Newton's method, then the results make perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

I would say he shape of the graph of function $\frac{-x}{x^2-1}$ the Newton's method converges only for |x|<1, see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B-x%7D%7Bx%5E2-1%7D

Comment: Well, if you're going to use WolframAlpha, then you can just ask it to [perform Newton's method for you](http://goo.gl/sQmBEo)!  That link starts at $x_0=1/2$. Starting at $x_0=2$, WolframAlpha says [there are no valid results](http://goo.gl/xsH5ft).

Comment: @MarkMcClure Thank you for the helpful advice.